# DataTables - Table Plugin for Jquery - Erro ao pesquisar string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

Bom dia estou usando o DataTables - Table plugin for Jquery, é um código do antigo desenvolvedor onde carrega corretamente os dados do banco porém, ele tem um campo "Procurar:" na parte superior onde digita algo e deve pesquisar na tabela, este campo não está funcionando.

Se eu digitar algo retorna o mesmo resultado de quando iniciado a tabela, ou seja, todos os dados da pesquisa sem qualquer where like (consulta).

O código é baseado em https://datatables.net/

**No arquivo da view eu tenho um código javascript:**

```
// ----- tabela de clientes

var oTable = $('#tblSearch').dataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    //searching: false,
    ajax: {
        url: "<?php echo $this->url('clients', array('action' => 'getFilteredClients')); ?>",
        type: "POST",
        dataSrc: function (json) {
            for(var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
                let f_active = json.data[i][1];
                let f_id = json.data[i][2];

                if (!f_active) {
                    json.data[i][0] = "<span class='client-disabled'>" + json.data[i][0] + "</span>";
                }

                json.data[i][1] = (f_active == 1) ? "Ativo" : "Inativo";

                json.data[i][2] = '<a href="/pgj/clients/' + f_id + '/load" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Editar"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a> ';
                json.data[i][2] += '<a href="/pgj/clients/' + f_id + '/delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="Apagar"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a> ';

                if (f_active == 1) {
                    json.data[i][2] += '<a href="/pgj/clients/' + f_id + '/inactive" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" style="opacity: .65;  filter: alpha(opacity=65)" title="Inativar"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></i></a>';
                } else {
                    json.data[i][2] += '<a href="/pgj/clients/' + f_id + '/active" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" title="Ativar"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>';
                }
            }

            return json.data;
        }
    },
    columnDefs: [
        { targets: "no-sort", orderable: false }
    ],
    columns: [
        { className: "" },
        { className: "text-center" },
        { className: "text-center" }
    ],
    order: [
        [ 0, "asc" ]
    ]
});
```

});

**No arquivo da controller eu tenho o seguinte código:**

```
public function getFilteredClientsAction()
{
    try {
        self::__autoload();

        $putParams = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        $limit = $putParams["length"];
        $offset = $putParams["start"];
        $orderByColumn = $putParams["order"][0]["column"];
        $orderByDir = $putParams["order"][0]["dir"];

        $orderBy = "";
        switch ($orderByColumn) {
            case "0": $orderBy = "f_name $orderByDir"; break;
            case "1": $orderBy = "f_active $orderByDir"; break;
        }

        $listCount = $this->clientsDAO->getFilteredClientsTotal();
        $list = $this->clientsDAO->getFilteredClients( $limit, $offset, $orderBy);

        $listData = [];
        foreach ($list as $client) {
            $listData[] = [
                $client["f_name"],
                $client["f_active"],
                $client["f_id"]
            ];
        }

        return new JsonModel([
            "recordsTotal" => $listCount,
            "recordsFiltered" => $listCount,
            "data" => $listData
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
        die();
    }
}
```

**No arquivo Model eu tenho os seguintes métodos relacionados:**

```
    private function getFilteredClientsQuery($limit = "all", $offset = 0, $orderBy = "") 
{
    $sql = "SELECT f_id, f_name, f_active from clients";

    if (!empty($orderBy)) {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY $orderBy ";
    }

    $sql .= " LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset ";

    return $sql;
}




public function getFilteredClients($limit = "all", $offset = 0, $orderBy = "")
{
    $sql = $this->getFilteredClientsQuery($limit, $offset, $orderBy);

    return $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->query($sql, array())->toArray();
}   

public function getFilteredClientsTotal()
{
    $sql = $this->getFilteredClientsQuery();

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(f_id) as total FROM (" . $sql . ") as counter";

    $result = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->query($sql, array())->toArray();

    return $result[0]["total"];
}
```

Comment: Até onde eu sei, o Datatables só consulta o banco de dados na hora de montar a tabela (quando se usa `serverSide: true`). O campo de busca funciona 100% offline. Se a busca não está funcionando, é difícil dizer o motivo sem testar. Já verificou possíveis erros no console?

Comment: Pois até onde entendi ele está carregando a base de dados corretamente e listando todos, posteriormente com base no campo consultado deveria filtrar esses dados "offline" e mostrar a pesquisa com base na consulta, o que não está funcionando.

Consultei o console e nenhum erro é abordado.

Notei que ao digitar ele pisca a tabela. Pelo que penso está funcionando mas não existe nenhum where para trazer os dados que interessa é como se estivesse faltando o código sql.

Comment: É como eu disse: a busca não consulta o banco de dados. Ela filtra a tabela no JS/HTML.

Comment: Entrei em um site e copiei um código exemplo da DataTables, e funciona com os dados de exemplo, porém, não consigo interligar os dados do meu banco de dados neste outro código. O que poderia solucionar, pegar um código funcionando e apenas carregar meu banco nele. https://zerobugs.com.br/ver-post/dica-da-semana-4-dica-da-semana-4-busca-filtragem-paginacao-e-estilizacao-rapida-de-tabelas-com-o-da/

Comment: Oi Sam, isso, eu entendi, eu estava achando que era o sql porém depois entendi isso, ele deveria filtrar os dados offline no JS/HTML, como você falou, foi ai que peguei um exemplo de outro datatable e tentei usar mas não consegui interligar o código antigo nele. Também não consigo fazer a consutla funcionar no atual, mas é isso que você falou, ele filtra pelo JS/HTML

Comment: O mais adequado seria usar o código antigo, apenas fazer funcionar este filtro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código PHP (especificamente a função `getFilteredClientsQuery`) não inclui nenhum `where` na query.

```php
private function getFilteredClientsQuery($name = "", $limit = "all", $offset = 0, $orderBy = "") 
{
    $sql = "SELECT f_id, f_name, f_active from clients";

    // deveria incluir o where abaixo
    if ($name != "") {
       $sql .= " WHERE f_name LIKE '%$name%'";
    }

    if (!empty($orderBy)) {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY $orderBy ";
    }

    $sql .= " LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset ";

    return $sql;
}
```

Mas uma observação: **não é o melhor exemplo pois está inserindo o valor da variável direto na query (poderia ficar vulnerável a SQL injection)**. Se você estiver usando PDO, o ideal é preparar a query e enviar isso como parâmetro. Pela sua outra função parece que ela aceita parâmetros, então talvez poderia fazer isso:

```php
// retira o name como argumento aqui
private function getFilteredClientsQuery($limit = "all", $offset = 0, $orderBy = "") 
{
    $sql = "SELECT f_id, f_name, f_active from clients";

    // deveria incluir o where abaixo
    if ($name != "") {
       $sql .= " WHERE f_name LIKE ?";
    }

    if (!empty($orderBy)) {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY $orderBy ";
    }

    $sql .= " LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset ";

    return $sql;
}

// coloca como parametro aqui
public function getFilteredClients($name = "", $limit = "all", $offset = 0, $orderBy = "")
{
    $sql = $this->getFilteredClientsQuery($limit, $offset, $orderBy);
    // pela assinatura do metodo query abaixo, parece que aceita input como parâmetro
    // você precisa verificar se é seguro
    return $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->query($sql, array("%$name%"))->toArray();
}
```

Comment: Oi Daniel, entendi seu código, é o que eu estava tentando fazer antes, até vou tentar usa-lo mas eu acho que é como o Sam comentou, ele está correto fazendo a busca sem o sql do where, pois quem faz a consulta de fato na tabela é o javascript já em cima dos dados que estão no html assim como este exemplo https://zerobugs.com.br/ver-post/dica-da-semana-4-dica-da-semana-4-busca-filtragem-paginacao-e-estilizacao-rapida-de-tabelas-com-o-da/

Comment: No caso acredito que é correto não ter o where.

Comment: Por mais que eu coloque o parametro neste método, eu não vejo em lugar algum onde o javascript está levando algum dado para passar por este parâmetro, o que ficaria voando o método, sem uso pela biblioteca entende ?

Comment: TUdo bem entendi acredito que é assim mas não consigo carregar o valor do input procurar para o método

Comment: Pelo [manual do datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side): "With **server-side processing enabled**, all paging, **searching**, ordering actions that DataTables performs are handed off to a server`. Tem outro exemplo do próprio datatables no [github](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php)